# PHPquery как засунуть каждый элемент найденный с помощью find в массив

Tags: php, phpquery

Читал документацию, там не нашёл такого, чтоб можно было разбить на массив найденные элементы. `<li class='good'>ASD</li>` этих good'ов много мне нужно оттуда некоторые удалить, некоторые оставить по этому решил каждый good отдельно засунуть в массив и оттуда уже удалить ненужный гуд. Без помощи регулярки.

Comment: есть же там метод `map`

Comment: А можно какой нибудь пример нигде не могу найти находится только jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Всё решилось библиотекой DiDOM. и вот таким вот маленьким куском кода 
    `$arr = [];
    foreach($posts as $post) {
    $arr[] = $post->text();`
  }